# Spring Boot safety of application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

is it safe to put in file application.properties security data, for example connection to my DB. for Example:

```
db.driver: org.postgresql.Driver
db.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
db.username: postgres
db.password: root
```

With safe I mean that data inside that file are not visible from web.

Comment: Yes, you can create a sample Spring Boot application, run it and request `/application.properties` using a web browser to make sure that the application does not serve back the content of that file.

Comment: You'd need to define what you mean by "safe" exactly.

Comment: @kryger I have edit the question.

Comment: Unless you put the file into a static resources directory the file will be obviously invisible to the outside world.